# Update execute parameter on a running Prometheus container

Tags: docker, prometheus

I have a running Prometheus docker container.  The command is

```
/bin/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/data/prometheus
```

I found the default DB only keep15 days data  according to document https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/

Is there a way that I can add the --storage.tsdb.retention.time flag on the running container?
That means it would like this

```
/bin/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/data/prometheus --storage.tsdb.retention.time=90d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to log into the container, kill the process and restart it with the new settings, but you will lose them at next container restart!

To make them persistent you should recreate the container with new ones, **but that solution will work only you stored container data into external volumes.**

Comment: yep, I would like to keep it persistent, so the only solution is to recreate a new container?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, I will move the data to external volumes and recreate one

Comment: You probably can't kill the process; since it has pid 1, and since stopping it would stop the whole container.  Deleting and recreating the container is normal here.

Comment: @DavidMaze you are right, so the only chance is the second option.